# obtener el valor del atributo y guardarlo en una variable con su nombre

Tags: javascript

cree un atributo **K**

```
 <div k="hola"></div>
```

y quiero que todos los elementos con el atributo **k** se guarde en un variable con el nombre del valor del atributo

```
  alert(hola); //hola porque el valor de "k" es hola
```

intente con esto

```
 var get={};
 window.onload=function()=>{
   var t=document.querySelectorAll("[k]");
   for (var i =0; t[i]; i++){
     var atr=t[i].getAttribute("k");
      eval("window."+atr+"=t[i]"):
     }
 }
```

pero no funciona ¿como le hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var objs = {};
  window.onload = () => { // No hace falta declarar una `function`, basta con una función de flecha
  const found = document.querySelectorAll("[data-k]"); // No va a cambiar, lo declaro constante
  /* Itero sobre cada elemento encontrado asignando al objeto
 un nuevo atributo con el valor encontrado en el data como nombre*/
  found.forEach((elm) => objs[elm.getAttribute('data-k')] = elm);
  console.log("Objeto final: ", objs); // Impresión final en consola
}
```

```html
<!-- Aquí he modificado ligeramente el nombre del atributo para seguir las reglas -->
<div data-k="test">Div1</div><div data-k="test2">Div2</div>
<div data-k="test3">Div3</div><div data-k="test4">Div4</div>
```

Creo que este código hace lo que necesitas, si he entendido bien la pregunta. Te dejo la explicación del código en los comentarios.

Si quieres ver cómo funciona exactamente el [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) te dejo el enlace a la documentación. Lo mismo con el [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) de los nodeList